Failure function of K.M.P algorithm
I'm studying tje Knuth-Morris-Pratt (KMP)  algorithm with the book Fundamentals of Data Structures in C.
In this book, it gives the definition of failure function f(j) in two different forms of statement.

If p="p_0p_1...p_n-1" is a pattern, then its failure function, f, is defiened as:

f(j)= largest i<j such that p_0p_1...p_i = p_j-ip_j-i+1...p_j, if such an i>=0 exists f(j)= -1, otherwise.

The restatement of failure function:

f(j)= -1, if j=0 f(j)= f_m(j-1)+1, where m is the least integer k for which p[f_k(j-1) + 1]=p[j] f(j)= -1, if there is no k satisfying the above (note that f_1(j)=f(j) and f_m(j)=f(f_m-1(j)))
I'm confused, about...
1.
What I understood from most data that I've search from the internet, failure function returns the length of the longest proper suffix of partial pattern which is also a prefix of pattern for any position within pattern.
However, what I understood from the book is that the failure function returns the end index of the longest proper prefix of partial pattern which is also a suffix of pattern for any position within pattern.

Is that difference because of 0-based and 1-based environments such as C and python?




The restatement said that f(j)= f_m(j-1)+1, where m is the least integer k for which p[f_k(j-1) + 1]=p[j],  f_1(j)=f(j) and f_m(j)=f(f_m-1(j))
Although I got an example to illustrate this from the site text
which gives an example as following:
pat= "ababyababa", find f(9) by f(8) for k=1, f(8) = 3 -> p[4] != p[9] for k=2, f(f(8)) = f(3) -> p[2] == p[9] so f(9) = f_2(9-1)+1 = 3
Why does the failure value can be determined by the one of the previous position recursively?
Why does it make sure that it won't miss any potential matching?
wiki, http://www.cs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/253/Syllabus/Text/Matching-KMP2.html

Copy and paste URLs; do not retype them. If you do type them, check for errors.

Is the title of the book “Fundamental datastructures in C” or “Fundamentals of Data Structures in C”?

Oppos. The correct site is https://www.cs.emory.edu/%7Echeung/Courses/253/Syllabus/Text/Matching-KMP2.html and book is Fundamentals of data structures in C. Thanks you for reminding!!
